# Python - Tensorflow saved model accuracy is lower than before saving it

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have set up my convolutional neural network in tensorflow, trained it on a dataset and evaluated it on unseen data. Doing this I got an accuracy of ~98% on the unseen data. 
Then i used

```
model.save("path/to/model")
```

to save the whole model to use it later. 
The model was saved successfully, however, i restarted the program, loaded that model using

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("path/to/model")
```

and evaluated it against the same data that i got 98% accuracy on, but this time i got ~96%. It is not that big of a difference, but i think it's not little either. Is that normal?
I have seen that many times in tensorflow, only the weights are exported, and not the biases but i don't know it that has something to do with this
This is my model structure:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 26, 26, 64)        640       
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 26, 26, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 13, 13, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 11, 11, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 11, 11, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 5, 5, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 3, 3, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 3, 3, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1, 1, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 10)                650       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 75,146
Trainable params: 75,146
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: You should have the exact same outputs for the exact same inputs. Probably you have a bug somewhere in your code. weights and biases together are refered to as "weights" in tensorflow/keras. So when weights are exported it means that the biases are exported as well.

Comment: Maybe you split differently between train data and validation data?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am using the MNIST dataset and for the validation i am using the test images that MNIST provides, so i am more than sure that the data is the same in both cases

Comment: I may add that i am getting 96% instead of 98% every time i load the model. I got 98% only with the validation  right after i trained it, other than that i always get precisely 96.29%

Answer (score -1):

It depends on if you have any random elements, for example, if you shuffle your training data or random initialize your weights from the start (which is the default). In that case, the algorithm will find a different local minimum and therefore yield different results.

If you want to always get the exact same results, input training data in the same order and use `tf.set_random_seed(0)`, which will make your initial weights always be the same.